# Xamarin.Android designer is VS bugs with the arabic language

Tags: android, xamarin.android, right-to-left, arabic-support

I struggled a lot with this, and i'v searched a lot also but found nothing.

I am using VS 2017 to develop a Xamarin.Android app, with the minimum SDK version of `Android 5.0 (API Level 21)` and a target SDK version of `Android 8.1 (API Level 27)`.

In the app, i am using the Arabic language, and i faced 2 problems :

1. The first one is that in the designer view, i can't get the direction of the layout to be RTL(Right to left), when i added the property : `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`, it worked only when i run the app on my physical device, but in the designer i can't get it to be RTL, i tried even changing setting in the toolbar in the designer view here :

[image]

2. The second one is that the arabic text value is being show as squares as also shown in the picture above.

I have tried rebuilding but also no chance, anyone have an idea or a solution for what's happening?

Comment: this seems to qualify for a [bug report for VS 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2017)